# Get new unique list containg only last occuring elements from original list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, replace, set

I'm sorry but I did not really know how to name my problem. I'm searching for the 'most pythonic' way to solve the following problem:

```
AA = [["a", 1], ["b", 1], ["c", 1], ["a", 3], ["b", 5], ["a", 7]]
BB = []
for elem in AA:
    if elem[0] not in [elemb[0] for elemb in BB]:
        BB.append(elem)
    else:
        BB[
            [belem[0] for belem in BB].index(elem[0])
        ] = elem
for elem in BB:
    print(elem)
```

That is: I have a list of lists, each containing two elements, and now I want to turn this into a new list, for which each first value of the list elements of the original list occurs only once.

The code above solves this task, that is, it turns

```
[["a", 1], ["b", 1], ["c", 1], ["a", 3], ["b", 5], ["a", 7]]
```

into

```
[["a", 7], ["b", 5], ["c", 1]]
```

just as I desired, but it is not very elegant, and I doubt if it is the best solution.

I came across one idea, by making use of a dictionary. The short version would be:

```
CC = {elem[0] : elem[1] for elem in AA}
BB = [[elem, CC[elem]] for elem in CC]
BB.sort()
for elem in BB:
    print(elem)
```

And the longer one (which I would need for several reasons):

```
CC = {}
for elem in AA:
    try:
        oldelem = CC[elem[0]]
        CC[elem[0]] = elem[1]
        print("Element '{:}' replaced: {:d} -> {:d}".format(
            elem[0], oldelem, elem[1]
        ))
    except KeyError:
        CC[elem[0]] = elem[1]
BB = [[elem, CC[elem]] for elem in CC]
BB.sort()
for elem in BB:
    print(elem)
```

The problem with the dict is, that it can become limiting, if the list elements become more complex, and one would have some additional restrictions for the replacement (i.e. some value is bigger / smaller than that of the element to replace etc.)

So now my question is: Is there a short / 'better' / cleaner way to accomplish this task?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want the the new list, can you be more specific?

Comment: For it looks like a bit of abuse of list comprehensions... that's all.

Comment: If your dict solution is too limited, please tell us where it falls short. If we don't know your requirements, it's hard to suggest alternatives.

Comment: @das-g: I thought the dict would become limiting, if I would have something like `A = [["a", 1, True, .123], ["b", 5, False .123], ["a", 7, True, .537] ]`, and than want have replacements for the first elements being equal, and the 4th elements being equal and so on.

Comment: @MichałF: Why does it look like a bit of abuse of list comprehensions? What would be your suggestion to improve it?

Comment: @AvinashRaj: The expected output actually is the one I get with the code - I just wanted to ask if there is a way to improve it.

Comment: @Hypnotoad Most of the people don't have any time to copy and run your code in-order to the see the expected output.

Comment: @Hypnotoad First, start from removing list comprehensions being an index into another container, this really looks but, is hard to read and hard to understand.

Comment: @Hypnotoad: Well - 5 answers yet with an avg rep of > 12k, all up-voted at least once but none is good enough for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an `OrderedDict` to keep the last occurrence of each pair:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> d=OrderedDict({i:j for i,j in AA})

>>> d.items()
[('a', 7), ('c', 1), ('b', 5)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since new key:value assignments to a dictionary will automatically overwrite the old ones, the answer is as easy as `dict()`:

```
>>> AA = [["a", 1], ["b", 1], ["c", 1], ["a", 3], ["b", 5], ["a", 7]]
>>> dict(AA)
{'a': 7, 'b': 5, 'c': 1}
```

Comment: Efficient and with built-ins only.

Answer (score 1):

A slight improvement over Kasramvd's answer:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> print OrderedDict(AA).items()
[('a', 7), ('b', 5), ('c', 1)]
```

Or if you don't care about efficiency (or if AA is short):

```
>>> print sorted(dict(AA).items())
[('a', 7), ('b', 5), ('c', 1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

The structure of `AA` is already fit to be used as initialization argument for `dict` or `collections.OrderedDict`, so you can simply do:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
BB = OrderedDict(AA).items()
```

Answer (score 1):

From the comments:

> I thought the dict would become limiting, if I would have something
>   like A = [["a", 1, True, .123], ["b", 5, False .123], ["a", 7, True,
>   .537] ], and than want have replacements for the first elements being
>   equal, and the 4th elements being equal and so on.

The nice solution of @TigerhawkT3's can easily be extended for that (additional, new) requirement:

```
import sys

items = None
if sys.version_info[0] == 3:
    items = lambda d: d.items()
else:    
    items = lambda d: d.iteritems()

AAA = [["a", 1, True, .123], ["b", 5, False, .123], ["a", 7, True, .537]]

def last_unique(arr, key_pos):
    return list(v for k,v in items(dict([aa[key_pos],aa] for aa in arr)))

for key_pos in range(0,4):
    print(last_unique(AAA, key_pos))
```

output:

```
[['a', 7, True, 0.537], ['b', 5, False, 0.123]]
[['a', 1, True, 0.123], ['b', 5, False, 0.123], ['a', 7, True, 0.537]]
[['b', 5, False, 0.123], ['a', 7, True, 0.537]]
[['b', 5, False, 0.123], ['a', 7, True, 0.537]]
```